# Java recursion function to convert a list to this data structure

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I have a **flat** `ArrayList` of this data structure

```
public class RecyclerItem extends RecyclerViewItem {

String text="";
boolean isProduct = false;
String secondText = "";
long parentId;
long Id;


}
```

Which extends this

```
public abstract class RecyclerViewItem {

private List<RecyclerViewItem> children;

private int level;

private int position;

private boolean expanded=false;

protected RecyclerViewItem(int level){
    this.level = level;
}

public void addChildren(List<RecyclerViewItem> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public boolean hasChildren(){
    if(children !=null && children.size() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

And I want to convert the ArrayList to a tree-like structure. Which means using `addChildren()` to build the structure. But I can't think of a way to use `addChildren` recursively here.

Note:

- I don't know how much depth there would be. This is why I am
  considering recursion instead of loops.
- I ommited the getters and setters of the two classes

Comment: Under which condition would you consider a `RecyclerViewItem` a child of other `RecyclerViewItem`

Comment: @AdwaitKumar when X's Id is a ParentId for Y. then Y is a child of X. The Id variable is omitted by mistake I will edit the question.

Comment: Do you really need recursion? As this can be done without recursion too.

Comment: I think I do need it because I don't know the depth in advance. i.e. how many levels of children there would be. @AdwaitKumar

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you don't need recursion you just need to group `RecyclerItem` by their `parentId` and then iterate through the list and keep adding the children you have found by the grouping.

```
    void updateChildren(List<RecyclerItem> recyclerItems) {
        Map<Long, List<RecyclerViewItem>> recyclerItemsGroupedByParentId = recyclerItems.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        item -> ((RecyclerItem) item).parentId)); // We can downcast safely since the list is actually of RecyclerItem
        for (RecyclerItem recyclerItem : recyclerItems) {
            List<RecyclerViewItem> children = recyclerItemsGroupedByParentId.get(recyclerItem.Id);
            recyclerItem.addChildren(children);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can we remove the elements from the flat list after we have added them as children?

Comment: In that case what is the `parentId` if a `RecyclerItem` does not have a parent. I am guessing there would be one or more such.

Comment: It would be zero

Comment: In that case you can just remove everything from your original list and addAll `recyclerItemsGroupedByParentId.get(0)` as it would contain all those `RecyclerItem` which don't have a parent and I am guessing that is what you are looking for.